# Access Laravel installation via IP instead of domain

Tags: php, laravel-4, arduino

I installed Laravel on my server, and i'm trying to access a url with a Arduino via IP. So instead of using www.domain.com/installation, it wants to go to 65.254.244.180/installation.

But when i try to go to the url. i get a 403 Forbidden error.

Is there a way to tell the server or Laravel to accept request via IP? Or is it another problem?

Comment: that'd be a server thing, and you'll have to tell the server that `65.254.244.180` is an alias for your `whatever.example.com` site's address. Until the webserver's configured to properly serve up your site on that IP, php/laravel never enter the picture.

Comment: But when i go to other files of folders on the server via IP they load as normal.